# Using Drools 5.4 - Can I have the rule file in the 'WEB-INF' directory?

Tags: java, spring, drools

I'm working on a Java Web application that uses Drools version 5.4. Is it possible to have the rule file (DRL) in the 'WEB-INF' folder, and if so, how would I reference it within the Spring config file for Drools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to have the rule files on your classpath. `WEB-INF/` itself is not on the classpath, but `WEB-INF/classes` and `WEB-INF/lib` are.

In Spring config files, you can reference to the rules as `classpath:myrules.drl`, for example.